# Fill a a form in an Iframe and get result of form submission bypassing same origin policy

Tags: javascript, php, proxy, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I want to fill a form on an external site and get the result of form submission whether the form was successfully submitted or not. Till now I have created an iframe but the problem is cross domain policy. Is there any way around it to fill up the form and press the submit button?

I do not have access to the other website that I want to fill form on, so all I have is the iframe and my own site.

Comment: You've tagged this *proxy* … which is the answer.

Comment: can you provide a link which i can follow ?